# socket.io - socket.emit, socket.on, socket.send

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Based from the official site of socket.io http://socket.io/#how-to-use, I can't find any terminologies.
What are the differences between `socket.emit` , `socket.on` , and `socket.send` ?  Can't find articles which differentiate between these things. I am currently developing a real-time application.

Comment: hello @Orvyl i want this question more , like socket.broadcast, socket.join , socket.in .... please

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`socket.emit` - This method is responsible for sending messages.
`socket.on` - This method is responsible for listening for incoming messages.
`socket.end` - This is the first time I'm hearing such a method. I am not really sure that it exists.

Comment: Socket.send should be seen as a low-level api (for custom protocols development, or cases where maximum messages per second speed is crucial), and Socket.emit a higher-level interface (for app development).

Comment: What is Socket.join()

Answer (score 1):

- `socket.emit` Creates events to send data
- `socket.on` listens for specific events to collect data
- `socket.send` Sends events of the name `message`